# UIActionSheet button segue into new ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to make the buttons on a `UIActionSheet` call segues which go to other view controllers. This is the code i have so far and it just crashes. The error message i get is "'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'Town''"

```
- (IBAction)CategorizeButton:(id)sender {
UIActionSheet* AS = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Group by"
                                                delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Town",@"Title",@"Location", nil];
[AS showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Town" sender:self];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Title" sender:self];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Location" sender:self];
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString* CategorizeTown = @"Town";
    NSString* CategorizeTitle = @"Title";
    NSString* CategorizeLocation = @"Location";

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:CategorizeTown])
    {
        CategoryTableViewController* CAT = [segue destinationViewController];
        // blah blah
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:CategorizeTitle])
    {
        CategoryTableViewController* CAT = [segue destinationViewController];
        // blah blah
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:CategorizeLocation])
    {
        CategoryTableViewController* CAT = [segue destinationViewController];
        // blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash. Include which line causes the crash and the full and exact error message.

Comment: @rmaddy it crashes exactly when it gets to one of these [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Town" sender:self];

Comment: You forgot to add details about the error message.

Comment: @rmaddy i dont know what to tell you all it says upon crashing is that its a SIGABRT error and this "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Is there a stack trace? That might be helpful.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 for details on how to do some debugging.

Comment: @rmaddy i have spend the last 6 hrs looking for answers and trying different things. i know how to debug and i know exactly what line it crashes on  and i am very frustrated because this project is due real soon.

Comment: @rmaddy im sorry. im very stressed out. i will look at the link :) thank you

Comment: No one here can help until you can tell us what the error is.

Comment: It could be possible that the destination view controller has problems initializing or that it's not the type you expect to handle. What type is destinationViewController when you debug into it? Does it initialize properly?

Comment: @rmaddy ok fair enough. where can i find the specific message you are talking about? all i can see is that it is a SIGABRT error in the thread 1, it happens at this line exactly : [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Town" sender:self]; and the debugger output shows this "ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: The link I gave you will help you find the error message but it should be in the debug console in Xcode.

Comment: @DepartamentoB not quite sure what you mean. it is a table view controller if thats what you are looking for and when i run the program it does not go into the destination view controllers viewdidload function at all. it doesnt even go into the prepareforsegue function in the original view controller from which the action sheet is being displayed. if i have a regular button segue into the destination view controller it works perfectly. i just dont know how to make a action sheet button do it

Comment: @rmaddy ahh i think i found it :) "'Receiver (<HomeTableViewController: 0x8c6bd90>) has no segue with identifier 'Town''" that is the message it gives me but i thought that all i had to do is "if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Town"])" in my prepare for segue function?

Comment: Update your question with that info so other can find it easily.

Comment: @rmaddy consider it done.

Comment: @rmaddy it may also be helpful to know that i dont actually have this segue link in my storyboard because i dont know how to link a UIAction sheet button to another view controller with a segue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard, select the segue.

[image]

Give it an identifier, (in your case, @"Town",@"Title",@"Location")

[image]